# Is there any degree for "intelligence studies" in Germany?

Tags: germany

[Intelligence studies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence_studies) is an interdisciplinary academic field that concerns intelligence assessment.

I have tried to find the relevant program in Germany, but i did not find anything.

Based on [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence_studies), every country might have its own standard for this field.

> In British universities, intelligence studies developed within
>   international history departments, while in US institutions it became
>   the preserve of political science, and even then the subject was
>   approached in terms of public policy and decision-making rather than
>   IR. Recently attempts to connect intelligence studies with
>   international relations theory have emerged, such as Andrew Rathmell's
>   work on a postmodern theory of intelligence.

The question is:

1. How is IS (intelligence study) in Germany?
2. Can you specify some links to the programms?

Comment: [Seems like its hasn't established itsself in Germany yet.](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://it4sec.org/system/files/15.1.06_intel_studies.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjthubeyN7eAhWLaFAKHWVDBWMQFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw1w00GzUNTkIef0umX2OtyG&cshid=1542565686175) I haven't heard of the field in Germany either, however that doesn't mean to much.

Comment: Sorry, we cannot provide links to relevant programs. Stack Exchange is not designed to accommodate list-based requests like this.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this field hasn't established itsself in Germany yet, and is mostly common in the anglophone world. However, the German Intelligence offers courses at the *Hochschule des Bundes 
Fachbereich Nachrichtendienste* (Federal University of Applied Administrative Sciences).

> [...] [T]hey focus on undergraduate education for 
>   generalists in intermediate-level posts.29 To some degree, the existence of this 
>   program also precludes the necessity of similarly-structured undergraduate 
>   programs at regular public universities. In the graduate and postgraduate sec-
>   tors, no similar program exists. ([source](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://it4sec.org/system/files/15.1.06_intel_studies.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjthubeyN7eAhWLaFAKHWVDBWMQFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw1w00GzUNTkIef0umX2OtyG&cshid=1542565686175), p. 86)

Contents of the answer and further information from: [source](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://it4sec.org/system/files/15.1.06_intel_studies.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjthubeyN7eAhWLaFAKHWVDBWMQFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw1w00GzUNTkIef0umX2OtyG&cshid=1542565686175)

Comment: The link is down. Could you please update your answer?